# How to get an free Azure account for testing Azure devOps project

Tags: azure, azure-devops, subscription, credit-card

I am trying to get a Azure free account but it needs a credit card at sign up. I don't have a credit card to get started. Is there an alternative for subscribing to Azure. I require this to work on Azure DevOps CD stage.

[image: Subscription]

This is required for working on Azure DevOps Labs. Since there is not much practical solution available out there for Azure DevOps, these labs provide very good base for learning the DevOps process. These labs require azure subscription which is a road block for even learning the process.

[image: azuredevopslabs]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a code related question. you should talk to azure support for this

Comment: It's impossible without a credit card, but you can vote on [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/170030-signup-and-billing/suggestions/8898328-credit-card-not-mandatory-what-if-no-credit-card), the Azure Billing Team says We are looking into alternate verification methods to accommodate the use case you propose.

Comment: Note that the link @IvanYang points to is about Azure billing and starting a trial there without a creditcard. I think this is different for Azure DevOps.

Comment: @4c74356b41 This is a generic question related to Azure DevOps. Anyone who is working on DevOps will need a azure subscription even for testing. Updated my question.

Comment: i understand, but there is a power user site for that

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create an Azure trial subscription. For that you need to have a creditcard available. They use that from preventing everyone from creating a new trial account after the first trial has been completed.

You want to create an Azure DevOps trial account. From the documentation [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/azure-devops-services/) they do indicate that you don't need a creditcard.

Can you try that page and confirm?

Answer (score 1):

You also have the option to use a dreamspark certified accoutn to get a free Azure License. These are available for students/teachers. Find more info at https://imagine.microsoft.com/en-us/Institutions/Index